# How does google detects that i don't have chrome browser installed in my PC and suggest me to install it

Tags: file, google-chrome, networking, browser, computer-science

Whenever I visit gmail or google website it suggest me to download chrome browser, how is google able to do that. I am trying to understand if google website reached over the Internet has access to my system files or file system at any point of time?

Answer (score 0):

It only shows if you go to www.google.com and your User Agent isn't from chrome. even after you install chrome it will still show that on other browsers.